# Folder Access denied when access was fine before

Tags: file, directory

I have a program that scans through a directory and just lists the folders within it. This has been working fine, but now for some reason it is coming up with an access denied error.

I have checked file permissions, all is fine, changed user password to ensure it has not expired. Even created a dummy directory, but the program states it can't even access that. Tried running the program as administrator, but still fails.

I have attached the code , I just don't know what has changed for this error to suddenly appear on any folder it tries to access.

The line throwing the access error is Using file2 As New IO.FileStream(foldername, IO.FileMode.Open)

I have tried the following

- Created a test folder with full permissions
- Changed user password under which the program runs
- Created a brand new project and re-entered the code
- Executed program while logged on with an administrators account.
- Updated visual studio with latest updates.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Partial Public Class Form1
    Public SQL As New SQLControl
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_analysis_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles btn_analysis.ItemClick
        Dim fileEx As String
        Dim sqltxt As String
        Dim ProtectedFileFlip As String
        ProtectedFileFlip = "jigsawdummyvalue"
        Dim FolderFlip As String
        FolderFlip = "jigsawdummyvalue"
        Dim FilePathCount As Integer
        FilePathCount = 1
        Dim FilesCount As Integer
        FilesCount = 1
        Dim DFilesCount As Integer
        DFilesCount = 1
        Dim TrueRec As Boolean
        Dim FileExt As String
        Dim ProtectedFolderCount As Integer
        Dim ProtectedFileCount As Integer
        Dim FileDeletion As Integer
        Dim yy As Integer
        Dim xx As Integer
        Dim aa As Integer

        TrueRec = False
        FilePathCount = 1
        FilesCount = 1




        'Load Protected File Paths
        sqltxt = "SELECT * FROM FilePath WHERE Action = 'Retain'"
        sqltxt = sqltxt.Replace("""", "'")
        SQL.ExecQuery(sqltxt)
        Dim ProtectedPath(SQL.RecordCount)
        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.DBDT.Rows
            ProtectedPath(FilePathCount) = r.ItemArray(1)
            FilePathCount = FilePathCount + 1
        Next
        'Load File Paths to delete
        sqltxt = "SELECT * FROM FilePath WHERE Action = 'Delete'"
        sqltxt = sqltxt.Replace("""", "'")
        SQL.ExecQuery(sqltxt)
        Dim RemoveFiles(SQL.RecordCount)
        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.DBDT.Rows
            RemoveFiles(DFilesCount) = r.ItemArray(1)
            DFilesCount = DFilesCount + 1
        Next
        'Load Protected File Extensions
        sqltxt = "SELECT * FROM Definitions"
        sqltxt = sqltxt.Replace("""", "'")
        SQL.ExecQuery(sqltxt)
        Dim ProtectedFile(SQL.RecordCount)
        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.DBDT.Rows
            ProtectedFile(FilesCount) = r.ItemArray(6)
            FilesCount = FilesCount + 1
        Next
        'Create file output header
        ListBox1.Items.Add("JIGSAW FILE ANALYSIS UTILITY VERSION 1.0.0")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("File Analysis commenced of " & foldername)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Analysis commenced at " & Now())
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Loaded " & FilePathCount - 1 & " protected file path definitions.")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Loaded " & FilesCount - 1 & " protected file extention definitions.")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Loaded " & DFilesCount - 1 & " file path deletion definitions.")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("----------------------------------------------------------------")
        Refresh()
        'Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(foldername, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        'Dim abc As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(foldername, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count() 'THIS RETURNS 217
        'Dim filecount As Integer = IO.Directory.GetFiles(foldername, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length 'THIS SHOULD RETURN 222 AS REPORTED BY WINDOWS





        'Try
        Const foldername = "C:\justtest"
        Using file2 As New IO.FileStream(foldername, IO.FileMode.Open)
                fileEx = file2.Name
                'My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(foldername & "Analysis", fileEx, True)
                aa = aa + 1
                For x = 1 To DFilesCount - 1
                    If fileEx.Contains(RemoveFiles(x)) = True And Not fileEx.Contains(FolderFlip) Then
                        'If fileEx.Contains(RemoveFiles(x)) = True Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(fileEx & " Located in " & RemoveFiles(x) & " contents of folder will be removed.")
                        FolderFlip = RemoveFiles(x)
                        GoTo mole
                    End If
                    If fileEx.Contains(RemoveFiles(x)) = True And fileEx.Contains(FolderFlip) = True Then
                        GoTo mole
                    End If
                Next
                For x = 1 To FilePathCount - 1
                    If fileEx.Contains(ProtectedPath(x)) = True And Not fileEx.Contains(ProtectedFileFlip) Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(fileEx & " Located in " & ProtectedPath(x) & " ignored, protected folder, all files will be archived.")
                        ProtectedFolderCount = ProtectedFolderCount + 1
                        ProtectedFileFlip = ProtectedPath(x)
                        TrueRec = True
                        GoTo mole
                    End If
                    If fileEx.Contains(ProtectedPath(x)) = True And fileEx.Contains(ProtectedFileFlip) = True Then
                        GoTo mole
                    End If
duck:
                Next x
                For x = 1 To FilesCount
                    'need to extract just the file extentions
                    yy = 0
                    xx = 1
                    For y = 1 To Len(fileEx)
                        FileExt = Mid(fileEx, Len(fileEx) - yy, xx)
                        If FileExt.Contains(".") Then
                            FileExt = Mid(fileEx, Len(fileEx) - (yy - 1), xx - 1)
                            GoTo rabbit
                        End If
                        yy = yy + 1
                        xx = xx + 1
                    Next y
rabbit:
                    For gg = 1 To FilesCount - 1
                        'we need to check the wild cards such as Ex*
                        If FileExt = ProtectedFile(gg) Then
                            ListBox1.Items.Add(fileEx & "  ignored, protected file. File will be archived.")
                            ProtectedFileCount = ProtectedFileCount + 1
                            TrueRec = True
                            GoTo frog
                        End If
                    Next gg
                Next x
                Refresh()
            End Using
            'Catch
            '    ListBox1.Items.Add("Unable to report on file.")
            '    aa = aa + 1
            'End Try
frog:
        If TrueRec = False Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(fileEx & " file will be deleted prior to archiving process.")
            FileDeletion = FileDeletion + 1
        End If
        TrueRec = False
        Refresh()
mole:
        Refresh()

        ListBox1.Items.Add("----------------------------------------------------------------")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("SUMMARY INFORMATION---------------------------------------------")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Analysis completed at " & Now())
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of protected folders identified--- " & ProtectedFolderCount)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of protected files identified------ " & ProtectedFileCount)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of files which will be deleted----- " & FileDeletion)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of files scanned ------------------ " & aa)
        MsgBox("Scan completed", vbOKOnly, "Completed")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I uninstalled all aspects of Visual Studio and reinstalled, problem still remains.  This would indicate that the computer environment is at fault some how.

Comment: Executed program on a different computer with Administrator logged on, problem remains.